# How to Change the Colors in Info Menu

Tags: theme

I've been able to use the User Preferences, Themes to change colors in my Blender inferface but I can't find the place to change the menu text color in the info bar.

[image]

I need to change "File," "Render," "Window" etc.. so that I can see them more easily. Perhaps to white or perhaps by changing the background to a lighter color.

Thank you for your help!

Sabi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in the "pulldown" part:

[image]

But it will affect all the pull down menus.

Comment: Thank you Lemon! I can't tell you how helpful this is! I've been playing with the settings for weeks! :-D I love the way you animated your response!

Comment: That one was particularly hard to find. I would have expected it to crop up on the Info settings.